# how to create a REST api for filtered data

Tags: api, rest

I've been reading a lot and I understand that a REST API maps resources with HTTP verbs. That's very easy of understand when, for example, a tutorial show an example like Employee. 
A PUT will be a new record (if it doesn't exist) or an update; a GET will extract a list with all employees, and a GET `api.example.com/employee/12` will extract the record for the Employee with ID = 12.

But, for example, how I could map a more useful queries like "get me all the employees with a salary under 50.000, with less that 2 years at the company and with the marital status  as single"?
In other words, how I could parametrize the query? Is it correct to add parameters like `api.example.com/Employee?salary<50000&years<2&marital-status=single" ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theory:

If you add parameters to your query, they are just part of the URL. The form of the URL does not tell you anything about whether your API is RESTful. Your API with query strings is restful if it obeys the constraints described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer and (optionally) follows the guiding principles

So as long as your query parameters don't do anything crazy like randomly change the state of some of the resources, then your API is still RESTful

The practice:

Any sensible REST API will need query parameters for the 'index' route. In practice, LinkedIn's REST API has query parameters that just select fields from someone's profile. In this case, the URLs looks completely different from yours, but still obey the principles of REST.

Your situation:

Your query strings can't contain inequalitites, only key+value pairs. You need to express it more like ?max-salary=50000&max-years=2&marital-status=single". You might also name your 'index' route differently: api.example.com/employees (plural)